# how to join two tables in sql with respect to same value comma seperated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

The question may be confusing but here's the example.

TABLE 1

```
|ID|  
1
1
2
2
3
```

TABLE 2

```
|ID| |NAME|
1     ROSE
1     LILLY
2    JASMINE
2    SUNFLOWER
3     LAVENDER
```

I want the output like this.

JOINED_TABLE

```
|ID|      |NAME|
1         ROSE, LILLY
2         JASMINE, SUNFLOWER
3         LAVENDER
```

Can Anyone please suggest me the query in SQL?

Comment: SQL Server 2000? SQL Server 2019? Something in between? Have you searched for anything? Have you tried anything? Why does `TABLE 1` have to be involved at all?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Its server 2017. I want to join two tables based on the same value. If TABLE 1 has multiple occurrences, I want to join TABLE 2 with the value associated with table one. We can do it with the normal join but I want the column values to be in the same column with commas separated.

Comment: My point was that you've simplified your sample data so much you've made it hard to understand why a join is even necessary (since a join can't possibly change the output). Also please always tag with the version of SQL Server you're using (otherwise we have to guess or ask you).

Comment: Only reason I can think of including `Table 1` would be in an `EXISTS` with the definitions we have.

Answer (score 1):

Table1 isn't needed in your example. You can use `string_agg` to get the desired output:

```
select id, string_agg(name, ', ')
from table2
group by id;
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you so much. Your answer made my day.